# DevComponents - Get out the properties "Name" and "Text" from SideBarPanelItems by Code

Tags: vb.net, dotnetbar

How can I get out the properties `name` and `text` from `SideBarPanelItem` or `SuperTabItems` with Code? I don't have a idea.

Used language: vb.net

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: I will collect the controls properties into a Datagrid to edit the Texts for a other language - translation of texts saved in a database